# richfaces 3.3.3 problem with ie6

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am working using richfaces 3.3.3 , tomcat 6. when i try to access my application using IE6 and the windows language is set to arabic, i get the following exception:

IllegalArgumentException: Parameter "size" for convert from HTML to java can not be decoded: [1px], reason: Unparseable number: "1px".

when i change the windows language back to english, restart the server and try to log in again everything works fine..

Can anybody please help me with this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [this](http://seamframework.org/Community/ParameterSizeForConvertFromHTMLToJavaCanNotBeDecoded11pxReasonUnparseableNumber11px) problem. Unfortunately it seems to be a bug in the `NumberFormat` class.

Comment: Seems like RichFaces is racist ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a workaround: In your rich:tabPanel, add the attribute headerSpacing="1" (without any unit). This will solve the parser problem. Took me quite a while debugging jsf and jdk to find out...

One more thing you need to do: In your skin, set generalSizeFont to a value without a unit. I.e. for example "generalSizeFont=11". Otherwise you will get the exception for icons (they will still work, though).